# Gtsummary: Footnote markers/numbers on header disappear when using as_kable_extra()

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, gtsummary

When knitting rmarkdown PDF using `as_kable_extra()` and `{gtsummary}`, the footnote markers tend to disappear from the header row, any way to retain them on the tables?

Example below:

```
library(gtsummary)
trial %>% 
  select(trt, age, grade)%>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)%>%
  add_p()%>%
  bold_labels()%>%
  as_kable_extra() # footnote marker "1" on header at p-value column disappears
```

[image: Output in Rmarkdown]

Comment: Does kableExtra support footnote markings? My recollection is that they are not supported. I just read the help file for `kableExtra::add_footnote()` and there is not an argument indicating where to place a footnote...just a string that will appear at the bottom of the table.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg, There are functions from KableExtra that you can use to manually add markers (numbers/symbols/alphabets) in the tables e.g., footnote_marker_number(), footnote_marker_symbol()…if that helps

Comment: You can post a GitHub Issue to the gtsummary repo with an example, I can see if this is something I can add to the package

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is as following:

```r
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, stage) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  add_p() %>% 
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}, N = {n}**$^1$",
                label="**Variable**", 
                p.value="**p-value**$^2$") %>%
 as_kable_extra(booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "", 
                            escape = FALSE, addtl_fmt = FALSE)
```

The key here is the combination of raw inline latex in `modify_header`, for example: `$^1$` and `escape = FALSE, addtl_fmt = FALSE` in `as_kable_extra` function.

It is also worth to mention that `result="asis"` in Rmarkdown code chunk didn't help. So I leave it with the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was having a similar issue and found a straightforward solution. The limitation of biocyberman's answer is that the `addtl_fmt = FALSE` option will affect *all* special characters in the table. My solution was instead to modify the outputted latex directly:

```
tbl_tex = trial %>% 
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_header(
   all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}, N = {n}**footnote1",
   label="**Variable**", 
   p.value="**p-value**footnote2"
  ) %>%
  as_kable_extra()

tbl_tex = gsub("footnote1","\\textsuperscript{1}", tbl_tex, fixed=T)
tbl_tex = gsub("footnote2","\\textsuperscript{2}", tbl_tex, fixed=T)
tbl_tex # spit out the table in an r code block with "result='asis'"
```